# How to apply Pagination to ViewModel in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was trying to apply [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-paging-to-index-method) to apply pagination, search box and sort to my ViewModel. Previous I was success to apply all these three functions with . However, for this `RolesViewModel`, since the result of `model` is a `List` while `AsTracking()` requires `IQueryable` so I used `model.AsQueryable().AsTracking()`. However, there was error when I try to render the page.

**Controller**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber, string name)
{
    var model = new List<RolesViewModel>();

    ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;

    if (searchString != null)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    // foreach to get each user from userManager.Users
    foreach (var user in userManager.Users)
    {
        // construct RolesViewModel object from user's attributes
        var r = new RolesViewModel
        {
            Id = user.Id,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Name = user.Name,
            BirthDate = user.BirthDate,
            PhoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber
        };
        model.Add(r);
    }

    foreach (var user in model)
    {
        user.Roles = await userManager.GetRolesAsync(userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(u=>u.UserName == user.UserName));
    }

    //return View(model);

    int pageSize = 3;
    return View(await PaginatedList<RolesViewModel>.CreateAsync(model.AsQueryable().AsTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
}
```

**Error in viewer**

```
InvalidOperationException: The provider for the source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncQueryProvider. Only providers that implement IEntityQueryProvider can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

Testing.Helper.PaginatedList<T>.CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize) in PaginatedList.cs
+
            var count = await source.CountAsync();
Testing.Controllers.AdminController.Test(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, Nullable<int> pageNumber, string name) in AdminController.cs
+
            return View(await PaginatedList<RolesViewModel>.CreateAsync(model.AsQueryable().AsTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
```

Comment: If you are using Entity Framework Core then you have to use this namespace: `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` instead of `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Yes I am using `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: This question is similar, and have a reply. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68056357/1362043