# Asp.net core PaginatedList with view model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, pagination

I would like to use PaginatedList with ViewModel , and send multiple entities in the view model.
When I tried this I got this error :

> The provider for the source 'IQueryable' doesn't implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider'. Only providers that implement 'IAsyncQueryProvider' can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.

**This is my view model**

```
 public class GalleryViewModel
{       
    public IEnumerable<ProjectPic> ProjectPics { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CoursePic> CoursePics { get; set; }

}
```

**PaginatedList (from Microsoft docs)**

```
public class PaginatedList<T> : List<T>
{
    public int PageIndex { get; private set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; private set; }

    public PaginatedList(List<T> items, int count, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);

        this.AddRange(items);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageIndex < TotalPages);
        }
    }

    public static async Task<PaginatedList<T>> CreateAsync(IQueryable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
    {
        var count = await source.CountAsync();
        var items = await source.Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
        return new PaginatedList<T>(items, count, pageIndex, pageSize);
    }
}
```

**Code behind**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Gallery(Guid Id, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? pageNumber = 1)
    {
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

        var projectsPics = await _projectPic.Entity.GetAll().Include(a => a.Project).ThenInclude(a => a.ApplicationUser).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

        var vm = new List<GalleryViewModel>();
        {
            new GalleryViewModel { ProjectPics = projectsPics };
        };

        var mock = vm.AsQueryable();

        int pageSize = 4;
        return View(await PaginatedList<GalleryViewModel>.CreateAsync(mock, pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
    }
```

**In razor view**

```
@model PaginatedList<GalleryViewModel>
```

Comment: I'm not sure. As long as I remember one time I got this error and it was because of wrong namespace. check your PaginatedList.cs namespaces.

Comment: The namespace is correct "namespace CorporateManagementSystem.Classes" @MoeinMohammadian

Comment: Sorry my bad. I meant using statements. If I remember correctly I used something else insted of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. I'm 80% sure that is your problem especially if you used intellisense to complete using statements.

Comment: You can see this [thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/2170186.aspx?Problems+in+implementing+Asynchronous+Action+The+provider+for+the+source+IQueryable+doesn+t+implement+IAsyncQueryProvider+Only+providers+that+implement+IAsyncQueryProvider+can+be+used+for+Entity+Framework+asynchronous+operations) may helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is in this line: `var mock = vm.AsQueryable();`. You can't do that. You are casting a `List<GalleryViewModel>` to a default `IQueryable` which has nothing in common with the `IQueryable` implementation Entity Framework is expecting (`DbSet`).

You'll have to use `DbSet<Gallery>` property or something similar that you have in your `DbContext` to make that query.